# Is it possible to plot stacked bar plots with 2 vertical y-axes?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, bar-chart

I am trying to plot a stacked bar graph with 2 vertical y-axes with a shared x-axes, similar to the figure below from Mashaki et al. RNA-Seq analysis revealed genes associated with drought stress response in kabuli chickpea (Cicer arietinum L.) PLoS ONE 13(6):e0199774. DOI:10.1371/journal.pone.0199774.

[image: Mashaki et al. RNA-Seq analysis revealed genes associated with drought stress response in kabuli chickpea (Cicer arietinum L.) PLoS ONE 13(6):e0199774. DOI:10.1371/journal.pone.0199774]

The closed I could get using plotly:

[image: Plotly-stacked bar graph]

Is this possible using plotly or ggplot?

Thank you!

Comment: Definitely possible using ggplot, I'm not sure about plotly but surely somebody will know. Do you have any sample data and code that you've tried? The nicest way to share sample data is to use built-in data or to use `dput()` so it is copy/pasteable.

Comment: Check this plot. I tried it with only 2 classes instead of 4 and it worked as the example you showed
https://r-graph-gallery.com/202-barplot-for-likert-type-items.html

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 1):

One option to achieve your desired using `ggplot2` would be to create a stacked barchart and use `labels=abs` to get positive values on the "second" or negative part of y-axis too.

Using some fake example data:

```r
dat <- data.frame(
  cell = rep(LETTERS[1:6], 2),
  type = rep(c("down", "up"), each = 6),
  DEG.DOWN = 1:12
)
dat$DEG.DOWN <- dat$DEG.DOWN * ifelse(dat$type == "up", 1, -1)

library(ggplot2)

dat$type <- factor(dat$type, c("up", "down"))

p <- ggplot(dat, aes(cell, DEG.DOWN, fill = type)) +
  geom_col(width = .6) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-6, 12, 2), labels = abs) +
  labs(y = "DEG.DOWN")
p
```

[image]

And using `ggplotly` you could convert the plot easily to a `plotly` chart:

```r
plotly::ggplotly()
```

[image]

Some more work is required if instead you also want separate titles for the axes. In that case I would go for an approach using `facet_grid` where I get rid of the facet look using theme options so that in the end it looks like one panel or plot. Note, just for nerdism I use `ggh4x::scale_y_facet` to set the `expand` argument separately for each facet.

```r
library(ggh4x)

p +
  facet_grid(type~., scales = "free_y", space = "free_y", switch = "y") +
  ggh4x::scale_y_facet(type == "up", breaks = seq(0, 12, 2), expand = c(0, 0, 0, 1)) +
  ggh4x::scale_y_facet(type == "down", expand = c(0, 1, 0, 0), labels = abs) +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside", 
        strip.background.y = element_blank(), panel.spacing.y = unit(0, "pt")) +
  guides(fill = "none")
```

[image]

One drawback is that `plotly` does not support all `ggplot2` options and hence the conversion via `ggplotly` is not that perfect as in the first case:

```r
plotly::ggplotly()
```

[image]